# the order of zero of rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

let's say at point $z=a$ we have zero of order $n$ to function $f$.

My Question is if there is fast way of knowing the order of zero to function $\dfrac{f}{g}$ in point $a$ where $g(a) \neq 0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For analytic functions, if $g(a) \ne 0$ then $f/g$ and $f$ have the same order of zero at $a$.

Comment: Thanks. do you have the proof ?

Comment: Hint: $(fh)^{(n)}(a) = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j} f^{(j)}(a) h^{(n-j)}(a)$ where $h = 1/g$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $f$ is a polynomial, the order of the zero $a$ in $f$ (and so in $f/g$ in your case) is the multiplicity (if any) of the root $a$ in $f$. It's also the maximal $n$ such that $f^{(0)}(a) = \cdots = f^{(n)}(a) = 0$.

Comment: Yuval, Thanks. I know the definition. I was asking that if the order of $f$ in $a$ is 4 so also $f/g$ ?